# django bootstrap 4 navbar toggler button not working on localhost

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, togglebutton

I am building a web app with **django** and **bootstrap 4** on localhost. I have loaded the **jquery**, **popper** and **bootstrap** on the end of my `body` tag on the **base.html** file. Whiles in mobile screen size, the `toggler` button doesn't work. It doesn't display my menu or close it. I don't know what the problem is. I have checked other solutions but it still doesn't work. Please help!

this is my code
'''

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Django blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Django blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Django Blog</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
                    target="#navbarResponsive">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">New Post</a>
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                        {% else %}
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                        {% endif %}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main role="main" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                            {{ message }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {% block content %} {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="content-section">
                    <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
                    <p class="text-muted">You can put any information here you'd like
                      <ul class="list-group">
                          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Lastest Posts</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                          <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
                      </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

Comment: possibly add some responsive metatags https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: I have added it but it is still not working. Any more ideas plz?

Answer (score 0):

try all jquery links above all bootstap links

Comment: The jquery links are above the bootstrap links but it is still nto working

Comment: No. I mean, above the bootstrap css as well in the <head>

Comment: You mean the links for the <link> tag or the links in the <scripts> tag? If for the <link> tag, plz share them with me. I can't seem to find them

Comment: try all <scripts> just below <head> tag